# Attributes and Inventory for child products of configurable

Tags: magento

I'm trying to display a list of of the stock status for the simple products related to a configurable product.  This is working fine except when for the first instance of the array when the related attribute 'Size' isn't display.

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $instock = "Next Day"; ?>
<?php $outofstock = "4 to 7 Days"; ?>
<?php $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product); ?>
<?php $col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('Size')->addFilterByRequiredOptions(); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($col as $simple_product){
    $qty = intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple_product)->getQty());   
    $size = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simple_product->getId())->getAttributeText('Size');
?>
  <li>
      <?php 
      if ( $qty >= 1 ) 
         {echo $qty, " ",$size," ",$instock;} 
      else 
         {echo $qty, " ",$size," ",$outofstock;}  ?>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The results set is looking like this:

```
99 Next Day
99 9 Next Day
99 8.5 Next Day
99 8 Next Day
99 7.5 Next Day
0 7 4 to 7 Days
99 12 Next Day
99 11.5 Next Day
99 11 Next Day
99 10.5 Next Day
99 10 Next Day
```

Any pointers on what I've got wrong and how to get the first attribute displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue was so much easier than to understand what is causing it! But let me address it in the correct order:

1. First of all, both `addAttributeToSelect` and `getAttributeText` actually operates with `attribute_code`, not `attribute_value` (which I believe you have as **size**, not **Size**).
2. So the first time Magento does `$product->getData('Size')` inside the `getAttributeText`, it returns `null`.
3. When you pass the **Size** to `getAttributeText` function, the **size** code gets replaced with **Size** for the particular attribute instance. How is it happening? Very simple: in the deepest layer of the methods chain, Magento makes next request to the DB:

   ```
   SELECT `eav_attribute`.* FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE (`eav_attribute`.`attribute_code`='Size') AND (entity_type_id = :entity_type_id);
   ```

   And if you have **collate** for your table as *case-insensitive* (*_ci), it will get the value no matter that actual `attribute_code` is "size". You can read more about collate in [official article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) and on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select).
4. So after the first `getAttributeText('Size')` function every consecutive `$product->getData('Size')` will return correct value.

Now returning to your script. Aside from **size-Size** issue you have few more little issues, but it would be great to deal with them for you to better understand Magento and php in general:

1. First of all, it's really a bad practice to use `load` function inside the loop - especially two times in a row, especially with the product object. If your configurable product has a lot of simples, you'll get unnecessary memory and time losses. It is way better to add all the data you need to your `collection`, and then use loaded products in the loop. BTW you've already added **size** to your collection using `addAttributeToSelect` function. **So the correct way to approach your issue would be**:

   ```
   $col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('size')
       ->joinField(
       'qty',
       'cataloginventory/stock_item',
       'qty',
       'product_id=entity_id',
       '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
       'left'
   )->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
   foreach($col as $simple_product){
       $qty = (int)$simple_product->getQty();
       $size = $simple_product->getAttributeText('size');
       // do your logic
   }
   ```
2. And second issue I wanted to mention, since you're in the `.phtml` template file, it's required from you to follow Magento template standards - using close tags for you loops and cases:

   ```
   <?php foreach($col as $simple_product):?>
       <li>
       <?php if ( $qty >= 1 ):?>
             <!-- some html -->
       <?php else:?>
             <!-- some html -->
       <?php endif:?>
       </li>
   <?php endforeach;?>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question and to explain things, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that loops should use this syntax while in template files. I open up way too many template files where other developers have not done this and left the code completely untabbed/unformatted. Seeing that makes me want to step on babies.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in ver. 1.7.0.2 you dont have to input AttributeText your self it will collect them automatic.

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
     $ids = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();  ?>
     <?php $instock = "Next Day"; ?>
    <?php $outofstock = "4 to 7 Days"; ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($ids as $id) :
    $simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); 
    $name = $simpleproduct->getName();
    $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty();?>
    <li><?php echo $simpleproduct->getName()." - ".(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
    ->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty();?>
     </li>   
     <li><?php 
     if ( $qty >= 1 ) 
             {echo $qty, " ",$name," ",$instock;} 
          else 
             {echo $qty, " ",$name," ",$outofstock;}
             ?>
     </li> 
     <?php endforeach;    ?>
     </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `Size` attribute is set on the first product?  I have tested your code using `shirt_size` as my attribute and my results return as expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to check the code.  Yes, 'Size' attribute is definitely set, it's mandatory and it's the only configurable attribute. Annoyingly the 'Size' dropdown does have the missing attribute in it, in this case Size 9.5, so I'm really at a loss as to what is happening.

Comment: If the product was based off an import or was updated using a mass action, try just to open that product in product management and re-save. Values tend not to stick sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show barcode attribute value. How can I show barcode value? Thank you for your help.

```
  <?
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                 ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
$stock_count=0;
$sizeqty="";
foreach($childProducts as $child){
 if($child->getAttributeText('ust_beden_no')!=""){   
 $sizeqty.="<Stok><isim>Beden</isim><Beden>".$child->getAttributeText('ust_beden_no')."</Beden><Miktar>".
(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child)->getQty()."



</Miktar></Stok>";
 

}
}
 return $sizeqty;
?>
```