# msqldb query is not acting as case sensitive

Tags: python, mysql, case-sensitive

Hi I'm trying to check if I already have an entry in a mysql table through python.  The key I use to check if their is already an entry is called PID and it uses the ascii_bin collation.  my problem is when when I try something like...

```
q = """select * from table_name where PID = '%s'"""%("Hello")
db = MySQLdb.connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx","temp",cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = db.cursor()
res = cursor.execute(q) 
rowOne = cursor.fetchone()   #fetches the row where pid = "hello"
```

rowOne ends up being the row where pid = hello.  However when I use sqlyog and execute the query it properly prints out the row where pid = Hello(Properly functions as a case sensitive query).  I'm looking for a way to get the mysqldb module to work properly as a lot of my code already is using this module

Comment: It is case insensitive, by default. Use binary comparison if you want a case sensitive select: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select

Comment: @alecxe in my question I already mentioned that my collation is ascii_bin and my select is case sensitive.  I have this working in just mysql, but when I try it through mysqldb it does not work.  The problem is purely python

Answer (score 0):

By default string comparison operations in MySQL are not case sensitive (or accent sensitive): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

You have two easy options though, use `COLLATE`:

> For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation:

or set the column to be case sensitive:

> If you want a column always to be treated in case-sensitive fashion, declare it with a case sensitive or binary collation. See Section 13.1.10, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question I am using ascii_bin collation which is a binary collation.  The problem here is not with mysql but with pythons module mysqldb

Comment: If you force it in the query on your search term with `collate latin2_bin` does it work? Agree this seems odd on re-reading.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work.  This is not a mysql problem it is a mysqldb.  I have this working perfectly in mysql

Comment: Have you tried logging what mysqldb is actually sending to MySQL?

Comment: Yes the cursor has an attribute called _last_executed, which shows that the query is actually select * from table_name where pid = 'Hello'

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea what else this would be. Also have no idea how mysqldb module could possibly introduce this issue.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have changed you code to: `q = """select * from table_name where PID COLLATE latin1_bin = '%s'"""%("Hello")` and still had the error?

Comment: Yes I used that exactly

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to try would be different permutations of this `q = """select * from table_name where PID = '%s' COLLATE latin1_bin """%("Hello")` or other case sensitive character sets on either side of the variable: `COLLATE utf8_bin` or `utf8_general_cs`. Is MySQL receiving the query you expect on each one of these? Are you able to set the whole table to a case sensitive character set for searching? : Alter the table to be something like: `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cs`? If none of that works I will put up a bounty for you - I am curious now.

Comment: The code I used in the question was not my actual code... My actual code had a ` error in it that caused the where clause to not be read.  The first entry in my table just happened to be hello, which is why I thought there was a case sensitive issue.  Thank you for your help though

Comment: So basically the universe conspired to throw you a red herring. Glad to hear it is worked out.