# Retrving data from MySql with case sensitivity

Tags: mysql

I have a Login table in MySql database . . In table there is a column by cname and one of the value is 'Raghu'. My question is when i write the query as

```
Select *from Login where cname='raghu';
```

Then it is retrieving the record which contains 'Raghu' . I want it to retrieve according to case . How can I retrieve with case sensitively, values in the data of tables.

Comment: Here is another link I found [MySQL case insensitive select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: [10.1.7.7. The BINARY Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html)

> The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string. This is an easy way to force a comparison to be done byte by byte rather than character by character.

```
Select * from Login where  binary cname='raghu';
```

Comment: Thank u , but is there any default option for this , because in project i have to use binary for all queries, it is little tedious .

Comment: @RaghavendraM actually this is good question. But I don't think there is any flag by using that you can make query case sensitive. At-least I don't know.

Comment: k . . and do you know what this line will do in query, /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */; this line was used in creating table

Comment: @RaghavendraM In Mysql by default collation is case-insensitive - `H` is equivalent to `h` and Using BINARY in the WHERE clause forces a match on the binary collation, which in English means that it matches actual characters by their character code. Read the link I given in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from Login WHERE STRCMP(cname,'Raghu')=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, you can use `LOWER` FUNCTION in either column name `LOWER('cname')` or in value `LOWER('raghu')`;

```
Select *from Login where LOWER(`cname`) = 'raghu';
```