# select from where value in column with comma separated

Tags: mysql

Below is my case

1: have a table with values like

```
dataval
Doctor,Enginner
DOctor
Labour,Doctor
```

now i want to select all value which as doctor in it how can it be done , can it be done using some my sql built in function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL case insensitive select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function **SELECT FIND_IN_SET()** like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Enginners', YourFieldName) > 0;
```