# Select query multiple ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables: categories and items.

```
table: categories

id | parent_id | name
------------------------------
1  | 0         | drinks
2  | 1         | soft drinks
3  | 1         | beer
```

and

```
table: items

id | category_id | name
----------------------------
1  | 1           | water
2  | 2           | coca cola
3  | 2           | pepsi cola
4  | 3           | stella artois
```

What I want to do? I want to **count all the items** in a category or in a subcategory of that category.

So if I select for the category "drinks" I want to count all the items in the category "drinks" but also all the items in the subcategories "soft drinks" and "beer".

I think it has something to do with a left join but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'd need a self-join on the categories table for the parent'd child stuff. and can your items ever be part of a "parent" category - will there ever be something that's got category_id=0, "drinks"?

Comment: @MarcB, since you're here. I have commented on a answer of yours yesterday. [Take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3936986/4802649)

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes it works! thank you very much!

Comment: @yesterday Please feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
select c.name,
       (select count(*)
          from items i
         where i.category_id in (select c2.id
                                   from category c2
                                  where c.id in (c2.id, c2.parent_id)
       ) as total
  from category c
```

This should produce:

```
name        | total
-------------------
drinks      | 4
soft drinks | 2
beer        | 1
```