# JSON Search in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am storing `destinations` field as `json` type in `mysql`

example column value `["Goa", "Moonar", "Kochi"]`

I would like to  get all rows that matches `goa` as destinations

However this row query returns the desired result

```
SELECT * FROM `packages` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(destinations, '["Goa"]');
```

But what is the eloquent equivalent of the above query??

Laravel version 5.3

Modelname :`Search`

Comment: Related [internals proposal](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/296).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably forced to use a partially raw query like:

`use DB;` (top of file definition)

`DB::table('packages')->whereRaw('json_contains(destinations, \'["Goa"]\')')->get();`

And if you have a model:

`Package::whereRaw('json_contains(destinations, \'["' . $keyword . '"]\')')->get();`

assuming your query above works in SQL.

Comment: How do i replace `Goa` with a variable like this `$keyword='goa'`

Comment: Just use string concatenation I suppose?

Comment: Got an error in sql syntax `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `finde_packages` where json_contains(destinations, '["Goa"]')`

Comment: Got it its a typo missing `)` at the end of  `json_contains`. One more question how do i remove case senstivity of the keyword??

Comment: Again a simple mistake `whereraw` always returns one row if keyword matches more than one row

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L652

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/json-where-clauses if you wanted it to be in the select, use `->selectRaw('...')` or `->select(DB::raw('...'))`

Comment: Its the problem with keyword case sensitive keyword

Comment: Good luck! I think this is starting to go off-topic from the original question now. I don't think you can search in a case insensitive way using this function. You would need to use a `where('x', 'like', '%z%')` or similar to get around the problem of case or maybe it's as simple as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select

Comment: @Jonathan what will be the opposite of json_contains. As, in this example, I want to get all rows whose destinations does not contain [GOA]

Comment: `not json_contains`

Answer (score 21):

In Laravel 5.6 and higher you can use whereJsonContains method:

```
Package::whereJsonContains('destinations',["Goa"])->get();
```

But not all DB support it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Laravel supports querying JSON column since Laravel 5.2. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#json-where-clauses).