# Search in JSON column using Laravel's eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've been working with Laravel 5.4's eloquent and I've encountered a problem.

I have a database table called **posts** and in that, a column named as `template_ids`. It stores the values in `json_encoded` format like:

```
["1","25","48"]
```

Now, I want to apply a filter to my query based on an array of IDs:

```
$id_access = array:3 [ 
  0 => "1"
  1 => "3"
  2 => "48"
]
```

What I am trying to do is to search if any of `$id_access` values is present in the database column, `template_ids`.

I tried:

```
Post::where('accessable_to',1)->whereIn('template_ids', $template_access_array)->paginate(3);
```

Also, I tried:

```
Post::where('accessable_to',1)->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(template_ids, ".$template_access.")")->paginate(3);
```

Already viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942374/json-search-in-laravel-eloquent), but it's not working for me.

Comment: May be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942374/json-search-in-laravel-eloquent will help you. Also you need to change the data type of your column template_ids as JSON in mysql

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: @AlankarMore I already added the link. I have seen this post

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR yes If i use contains. it gives me json_contains does not exist.

Comment: check your mysql version, if it supports json_contains or not

Comment: or try to give json_contains in lower case in your query

Comment: Have you used json_contains with DB::table instead of Post::whereRaw?

Comment: @AlankarMore that doesn't have any effect. I tried it.

Answer (score 7):

To see if the `template_ids` JSON field contains "any" of the values in a needle array, you gonna need to utilize multiple `OR`'d [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) conditions which requires MySQL 5.7:

```php
$ids = ['1', '3', '48'];

Post::where('accessable_to', 1)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($ids) {
        $firstId = array_shift($ids);

        $query->whereRaw(
            'JSON_CONTAINS(template_ids, \'["' . $firstId . '"]\')'
        );

        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $query->orWhereRaw(
                'JSON_CONTAINS(template_ids, \'["' . $id . '"]\')'
            );
        }

        return $query;
    });

return Post::paginate(3);
```

Laravel's query builder will produce a query like:

```php
SELECT * FROM "posts" 
WHERE "accessable_to" = ? AND (
    JSON_CONTAINS(template_ids, '["1"]') OR 
    JSON_CONTAINS(template_ids, '["3"]') OR 
    JSON_CONTAINS(template_ids, '["48"]')
)
```

Which targets records that have any of those IDs in their `template_ids` JSON-typed field.

You might be interested in reading a related Laravel [internals proposal](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/296).

Comment: Is it possible to remove one `template_ids` in the above case on bulk? That means remove `'1'` from all rows if there is `1` in templates_ids columns

Comment: @SarojShrestha This answer might be helpful: [Remove array element by value in mysql json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678277/65732)

Answer (score 0):

What about to say:

```
$query = Post::where([]);

$query->where(function($query, $template_ids){
  foreach ($template_ids as $id){
     $query->orWhere('searching_field', 'like', '%'.$id.'%');
  } 
});

$query->get()
```