# Laravel's query builder JSON selector `field->key` causes syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mariadb

So, I want to query the `notifications` table in Laravel by comparing a certain ID with the `data` column. This is how `data` column looks like:

```
{
    "Message": "some message",
    "id": 3
}
```

Now, I need to select all the notifications that have an ID that is equal to 3. Here is how I was trying to do it:

```
DB::table('notifications')->where('data->id', '3')->get();
```

But this throws the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."id"' =
>   ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `notifications` where
>   `data`->'$."id"' = 3)

I am losing my mind here, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Laravel stores JSON as text, so you can't query it this way.

You need change the way that you store this information in order to query it, otherwise you will need to do a fulltext search like `data LIKE '%"id": 3%'`, but this kind of queries are very slow.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669673/laravel-eloquent-search-in-json-values-of-database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your query. It's your environment.

### Problem

Laravel's [`MySqlGrammar`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L235-L246) translates the `field->key` notation in field names (on Laravel side) into `field->'$.key'`-style extractions (on MySQL side):

```php
/**
 * Wrap the given JSON selector.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
protected function wrapJsonSelector($value)
{
    $path = explode('->', $value);

    $field = $this->wrapValue(array_shift($path));

    $path = collect($path)->map(function ($part) {
        return '"'.$part.'"';
    })->implode('.');

    // Here:
    return sprintf('%s->\'$.%s\'', $field, $path);
}
```

I just confirmed that MariaDB does not support the [`->` extraction operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) as an alias to the [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function. However, the same query works against a vanilla MySQL 5.7 server.

Assuming this `test` table:

```php
╔════╤══════════════════╗
║ id │ payload          ║
╟────┼──────────────────╢
║  1 │ {"a": 1, "b": 2} ║
╚════╧══════════════════╝
```

A query that uses the `->` extraction operator:

```php
SELECT payload->"$.b" FROM test;
```

fails against MariaDB 10.2.8 while it yields a correct `2` against a MySQL 5.7.19 server.

### Solutions

The right solution depends on what you're using on production.

#### Replace MariaDB

If you're using MySQL, replace MariaDB with MySQL in your development env. On a macOS machine managed by homebrew, it'd be as easy as:

```php
brew services stop mysql
brew uninstall mariadb
brew install mysql
brew services start mysql
```

your data will remain intact.

#### Rewrite your queries

However, if you're using MariaDB in production, you need to rewrite your queries to use `JSON_EXTRACT()` function as [Elias already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282603/65732). As you can see you need to be much more verbose with the Laravel API.

The above query would be:

```php
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(payload, "$.b") FROM test;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that only *MySQL* supports the `->` operator, then the query will fail on *MariaDB*, but:

Both *MariaDB* and *MySQL* supports the `JSON_EXTRACT` function, that parses the *JSON* and get a value from it.

You can solve it by doing a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`notifications.data`, "$.id") = 5
```

To do it with [Laravel's Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries), you'll need to use `DB::raw` method:

```
DB::table('notifications')->where(DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(`notifications.data`, "$.id")'), '=', 3);
```

Please try it and tell me if go wrong.

**Note:** The `JSON_EXTRACT()` is only available on `MySQL >= 5.7` or `MariaDB >= 10.2.3`

**Thanks** to @Sepehr, I didn't know that the `->` was an MySQL Operator, neither that JSON type existed. :-)

Comment: Even though your answer works "around" the problem, it does not answer the question. Your statement that Laravel stores JSON as a string [is false](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L695-L698), it's a JSON-typed field, not a string-typed one. Besides that, since Laravel 5.3, you can target JSON-typed field keys [using the `->` notation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L235-L246) instead of using `JSON_EXTRACT` in raw queries that you've suggested.

Comment: You're still not answering the actual problem. Both the [JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) and the [`->` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) exist. But you are right on the storage type; Laravel's JSON-typed fields are getting created as `longtext`-typed fields and are strings. But you should still be able to query them using the arrow notation without syntax errors. It's in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#json-where-clauses).

Comment: The actual problem is that the [`->` extraction operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) that gets [built by Laravel's MySQL grammar](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L235-L246) throws that syntax error when executed against MariaDB.

Comment: I just confirmed this, MariaDB does not support the `->`. However the same works against a MySQL installation.

Comment: @sepehr, so as I said on my answer, the JSON_EXTRACT solves the problem, right? :-)

Comment: Interesting! Thank you both for your input. I gave up at some point and just re did my query in a different way. Everything is working fine now. 

Btw, I tried the JSON_EXTRACT method but it didn't work either. It was throwing an error that the method does not exist.

Comment: @EliasSoares As I said, your initial input was not answering the question, it was a workaround without even mentioning the root cause. But now that you have edited your answer [and  deleted your comments], it makes perfect sense 

Comment: @Chiipepper Your issue with `JSON_EXTRACT` must have been a version issue with your installation of MariaDB. Elias has mentioned the version requirement above, check whether you're meeting that, `mysql --version`.

Comment: Yep, that's correct, the version was quite out of date.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the `->`, i think you have a **var** called **$data** with some collection in it. 
If that so then the correct way is:

```
DB::table('notifications')->where($data->id, '3')->get();
```

Or if you have a Model related to **notifications** table then:

```
Notification::where($data->id, '3')->get();
```

If the `Model` is called `Notification` (following Eloquent convention)

But if you tried to find all ID's equals 3 then just:

```
DB::table('notifications')->where('id', '3')->get();
```

Comment: That `->` notation in OP's question is a [special Laravel notation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L254-L257) to access JSON fields' keys. It will be eventually translated to MySQL's corresponding [operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path). Having said that, your answer is totally irrelevant to the problem. Welcome to SO though.

Comment: I do understand about JSON I guess I misinterpreted the question