# Laravel Field Syntax Returns error or access Violation

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

There seems to be an identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282286/laravels-query-builder-json-selector-field-key-causes-syntax-error), however, the context of that question is based around MariaDB and I am using MySQL. I'm not sure if this is related code or a server configuration?

When I try to query JSON data in Laravel 5.4...

```
$dataCheck = DB::table('station_data')
    ->select('entry_data')
    ->where('entry_data->status', '=', $data)
    ->where('station_id', '=', $stationID)
    ->first();
```

I get the following error...

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."status"' =
>   ? and `station_id` = ? limit 1' at line 1 (SQL: select `entry_data`
>   from `station_data` where `entry_data`->'$."status"' = test and
>   `station_id` = 7 limit 1)

I'm not sure why it's adding the `$` symbol and messing with the syntax

Comment: It's converting the Eloquent query to use MySQL JSON query syntax. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Your MySQL version is not 5.7.

Comment: Yes, thanks, its 5.5, thats the problem.