# Select case insensitive using php and pdo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How to make this sql statement case insensitive as to accept `$_POST["CatType"]]` to be `wet-beans` or `Wet-beans` or `WET-BEANS`?

```
$stmt ="SELECT distinct Product_Name FROM Products WHERE Product_Name='".$_POST["CatType"]."'And Category_ID=(SELECT Category_ID from Categories WHERE Category_Name='".$_POST["CatName"]."')";
```

Comment: One way is to wrap both sides with `lower` or `upper` but be mindful that it will result in indexes on those column being useless to your query if any.

Comment: Which rdms are you using?

Comment: Similar question already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select)

Comment: Well, I should have clarified, is this MySQL?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin, and i tried `lower` or `upper` but doesn't work