# Spring data JPA existsByField is case insensitive in MySQL, how to make it case sensitive

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

ClientsRepository class

```
public interface ClientsRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientsEntity, Long> {

    boolean existsByClientId(String clientId);

}
```

ClientsEntity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class ClientsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String clientId;

}
```

clients table
`|      id             |     client_id    |
 |---------------------|------------------|
 |       1             |         ABC      |
 |---------------------|------------------|`

When calling existsByClientId("abc") it returns true, how can I force to check case?

Actual result:
`existsByClientId("abc") --> true`
`existsByClientId("ABC") --> true`

Expected result:
`existsByClientId("abc") --> false`
`existsByClientId("ABC") --> true`

> Java version 8
>   Spring boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE
>   mysql-connector-java version 5.1.46

Comment: If the content is truth, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select).

Comment: @samabcde I have added the actual result, please have a look, and also edit my question.

Comment: Please check the collation by following ostrokach's answer (link in my previous comment). I suppose the case insensitive problem is due to database instead of the program.

Comment: @samabcde Ohk got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the SQL query derived is case sensitive. However, as said in the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

> The method parser supports setting an IgnoreCase flag for individual properties (for example, findByLastnameIgnoreCase(…)) or for all properties of a type that supports ignoring case (usually String instances — for example, findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(…)). **Whether ignoring cases is supported may vary by store, so consult the relevant sections in the reference documentation for the store-specific query method**.

As we are using MySQL database, and the case sensitivity depends on server, database and connection collations, and the [default collation(utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-applications.html) is case insensitive, making the comparison case insensitive. Creating unexpected result when comparing to other database.

From solution of [MySQL case insensitive select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select), changing the column collation to case sensitive is simplest and no code change is required.