# Wildcard Search in MySQL, LIKE '%string%' (Fiddle)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, case-sensitive

I want to search data with condition `name = '%Park%'`

this is my sample code in Fiddle.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0e059/12

when I tried in BigQuery, It returns case sensitive result.
data exactly match with 'Park'. not 'PARK','park'

But in mySQL test which I linked,
it returns all alphabetic 'Park' contains 'PARK','park'
(no case sensitive)

Does mySQL originally NO CASE SENSITIVE EVEN IN DATA?
Or did I go wrong in something??

Comment: Compare the 2 collation settings

Comment: sorry but can you explain more about 2 collation settings?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: See the following answer to the duplicate question for the most comprehensive answer that goes beyond binary operator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35029976/5389997

Answer (score 0):

For case in MySQL you can use `LIKE BINARY`;

```
SELECT name, host_name, borough, district, price
FROM airbnb
WHERE name LIKE BINARY '%park%';
```

[MySQL like binary](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/9c44ab38c603bef2eb94a8232ab86fbd/)