# How to select an entry from a MySQL database by searching for a case-sensitive username

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, collation

I have set up a MySQL database and created a login table using MySQL Workbench. I am using a MySQL 8.0 server.

The login table consists of the simple entry:

```
id    username    password
1     MyUser      somePassword
```

When performing EITHER of the following SQL Queries, the single entry of my login table is retrieved:

```
SELECT * FROM my_database_schema.login WHERE username="MyUser";
SELECT * FROM my_database_schema.login WHERE username="myuser";
```

I only want the query to be successfull, however, if `username="MyUser"`. In other words: I want my SQL query to be case-sensitive.

As has been pointed out in the comments, this issue appears to be related to the database collation. I have, therefore, tried out one of the answers to the question linked in the comments.

I have performed the following query to check my current collation:

```
show variables like '%collation%';
```

This query yields the following answer:

```
Variable_name                    Value
collation_connection             utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
collation_database               utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
collation_server                 utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
default_collation_for_utf8mb4    utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

As this is not a case-sensitive collation, I know that I have to change this, for example to `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`.

In order to achieve this, I have performed the next two queries:

```
-- Change database collation
ALTER DATABASE `my_database_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;

-- Change table collation
ALTER TABLE `login` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;
```

MySQL workbench lets me know that these queries have been successfull. Still, when performing the first query, i.e. checking for the database collation again, I obtain the same result as before: I am using `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

Can somebody help me understand this?

===========================================================
Searching for more possible answers in the linked question, I have tried out the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_database_schema.login WHERE username= BINARY "MyUser";
```

And that's doing the trick! This query will only be successfull, if the username is given in the correct case-sensitive way.

However, I don't know how to convert this query into a HQL statement, i.e. a query that's understood by Hibernate. At the moment, I am using the following statement:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username=?1")
```

, where User is the class representing my login table.

Comment: You might want to share your `UserDetailsService` and database config. Case sensitivity in this case is mostly about db configuration.

Comment: What database do you use? MySQL?

Comment: I haven't found the database.config file, on windows it's suppossed to be located at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`, but there's nothing there. But simply retrieving an entry from my database usually is case-sensitive, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: is a SELECT statement case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-is-a-select-statement-case-sensitive)

Comment: @dur: thx for the link, this is really helpful! Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. For some reason, changing the database collation does not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a collation with `_cs` or `_bin`.  Apply that to the *column* in question.

A Database's collation is the *default* for new tables.
A Table's collation is the *default* for any columns in it for which the charset and collation are not specified.

To find all the available collations:

```
SHOW COLLATION;
```