# Is each data unique in rdbms columns

Tags: mysql, sql

A column in mysql consists of a 'SQL' and another value is 'sql'.

```
select col from table_name where col = 'SQL';
```

Does this return both SQL and sql.

Comment: it depends on whether the table and column use case-insensitive collation.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35029976/5389997 answer from the duplicate question for a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Case-sensitivity is determined by the collation of a column. The default collations are case-insensitive, so the string comparison you show would match both "sql" and "SQL".

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

If your column has a binary collation, or if the column is a binary string (data types `BINARY`, `VARBINARY`, `BLOB`), then the string comparison will be case-sensitive.